# One IV 100% dependent on another IV; to use sample or full population?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, interaction, least-squares, stata

For some reason, I'm having trouble working this out in my mind.

My two independent variables of highest interest are a health condition and treatment for that health condition, and their impact on overall health costs for a population.

If someone does not have the health condition, there is no circumstance in which they would receive treatment for it. So, condition=0, treatment must also =0. If condition=1, they may or may not have received treatment for it.

I want to know how much the condition impacts total costs, and, if someone has the condition, how treatment may/may not ameliorate that impact.

Is just doing a standard OLS regression, including both those dummies, sufficient? It feels off, but maybe it's not.

I thought of doing two different regressions; one with the full population, just looking at the impact of the condition, and then doing a regression on just those with the condition, with treatment as the primary IV there.

An interaction term doesn't make sense to me, since one of the variables will always be zero if the other this. Treatment cannot exist without the condition.

Comment: Why not do a regression of costs on a constant, a dummy for treated and condition, and a dummy for condition and untreated?

Comment: Thank you, Dimitriy--that seems logical!

It would also seem reasonable to do a ttest on the costs between the groups.